# CSS Dropdown menu [HELP]

Tags: html, css

Hello i have problem with the drop-down menu link to the menu when you hover product the drop-down menu is weird and i struggle can you please help ?
thank you

The HTML:

```
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="home"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="faq"><a href="c">Products</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">TEST</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEST</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEST</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="service"><a href="price.html">Pricing</a></li>
    <li class="contact"><a href="f">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="logout"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
body {margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #ccc;}
.nav ul {list-style: none;
    background-color: #1dde1d;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;}
.nav li {font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #888;}
.nav a {text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    transition: .3s background-color;}
.nav a:hover {background-color: #23c823;}
.nav ul li ul li {display: none;}
.nav ul li:hover ul li{display: block;}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .nav li {width: 120px;
        border-bottom: none;
        height: 50px;
        line-height: 50px;
        font-size: 1.4em;}
    #container {min-height:100%;
        position:relative;}
    .footerWrap {width:100%;
        position:fixed;
        bottom: 0px;}
    .footer {width:200px;
        margin:auto;}
    .footerContent {float:left;
        width:100%;
        background-color:#009900;
        padding:1px 0;}
    .footer p {float:left;
        width:100%;
        text-align:center;}
    /* Option 1 - Display Inline */
    .nav li {display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: im sorry im new here

Comment: how you want dropdown menu?

Answer (score 0):

Remove   `height: 40px;` from `.nav li` and add `position: relative;` to `.nav ul` it works well.

```
.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #1dde1d;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative; //added position.
}
```

Check Your updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gfxexjbn/2/) here.

Answer (score 0):

At a sheer guess based on the limited info in the question... try this CSS:

```
.nav ul li {position:relative;}
.nav ul li ul {position:absolute;top:100%;}
```